# Getting value from dynamic select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am auto submitting a form via ajax after a select box has been changed...

Here is the select box:

```
<select id="parent:<?php echo $subject[0]['id']; ?>" contenteditable="true" style="padding:7px;">
<?php 
    foreach ($subject_list as $item) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo stripslashes($item['id']); ?>"><?php echo stripslashes($item['name']); ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Here is the code which submits and echo's back some JSON...

```
$(function(){
 $('.select_change').change(function(){
        $( ".form-errors" ).hide(); //Hide errors
        var field_id = $(this).attr("id") ;
        var value =  $(this).value() ;
        $.post('data/SUBJECTS_edit.php' , field_id + "=" + value, function(data){
            if(data.validation != 1)
            {
                $( "#" + data.fieldName + "\\:" + data.subjectID ).show().effect('highlight', {color: '#c0ffb9'}, 1500); // Show green fade
                $( "#" + data.fieldName + "_msg\\:" + data.subjectID ).hide(); //Hide errors
                $('#' + data.subjectID + '-' + data.fieldName).html(data.value); // Change data in list
            }else{
                $( "#" + data.fieldName + "\\:" + data.subjectID ).show().effect('highlight', {color: '#e29292'}, 1500); //Show red fade
                $( "#" + data.fieldName + "_msg\\:" + data.subjectID ).show(); // Show error DIV
                $( "#" + data.fieldName + "_msg\\:" + data.subjectID ).text(data.response); // Input text into error DIV
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Every thing works fine, except **value** is coming back as the following...

```
fieldName: "parent"
original: "0"
response: "Details Updated"
status: 200
subjectID: "1"
validation: null
value: "Art\n   English\n   Zoology\n   Mathematics\n   Design"
```

It's selecting the text, rather than the value, and its select all items in the list instead of the one selected.

I'm sure there is a bit of javascript I'm missing here but I haven't yet figured it out

Comment: Can you post the actual `select` HTML. Also, I don't see how this works, as the jQuery method is `val()`, not `value()`.

Comment: `var value = $(this).val()` is the correct syntax for what you want - also why is it `contenteditable` ??

Comment: Change `$(this).value()`to `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 0):

Ignore me. Newbie mistake. I didn't have the select_change class applied to the select box! Working now

Comment: Please add that information to the question instead and then close the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var value = $(this).val()
```

or alternative is

```
$('.select_change option:selected').val();
```